# How to export part of the bash script as external file

Tags: bash

I write a script that manages creation of creation of lxc virtual container. It consists of a part that is executed on the host, and part that is executed by the container (a virtual guest). It would be more elegant if I could write both scripts in on file, and extract the second script from it when it is needed (and subsequently run on the container).

I vaguely remember, that there is a way to do that in bash, but I don't know how to find the name of this feature and how to use it.

I need something like this:

```
#/bin/bash

# here are commands that are to
# be executed by the host

<declare start of the code chunk that will be exported to file>

    # here go commands that 
    # need to be invoked by the guest

<end of code chunk. Paste the above code into the /var/lib/lxc/<mycontainer>/rootfs/tmp/second-stage.sh>

sudo lxc-attach -n <container name> /tmp/second-stage.sh
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a [here document](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Here-Documents) to redirect multiline text to the file in question. Since your document body consists of code you will want to disable parameter substitution to avoid funny side effects by quoting the heredoc delimiter string (`'EOT'`):

```
[...]
cat >/var/lib/lxc/<mycontainer>/rootfs/tmp/second-stage.sh <<'EOT'
# your text/code goes here
EOT
[...]
```

Comment: Exactly this. Isn't there any build-in method that doesn't involve running external programs (`cat`)?

Comment: The text of the here document becomes the standard input of a command, but I don't think there's a built-in command that'll copy its standard input to a named file.  Commands are cheap, and `cat` is a cheap command.  Prove it's a bottleneck (it won't be) before worrying about it.  (First law of optimization: Don't do it. Second law of optimization — for experts only: Don't do it now.)

Comment: You could use `printf` or `echo` instead of `cat`; you can embed newlines in a string. But the time it would take to edit your file is probably longer than the time you will *ever* save compared to forking `cat`. :)  Also, I *think* that `echo "$(</dev/stdin)"` would simulate `cat` without forking a new process.

Comment: @chepner For me, this does work in a pipe but not with a heredoc and while there's probably an evident explanation I'm too tired to figure out why. Since OP is so concerned about this single `cat` it should probably also be noted that `bash` creates a temporary file for here documents (is that why the above doesn't work with a heredoc?) (`/tmp/sh-thd-*`) so there you go, even more overhead! A fork *and* a temporary file :-) However, it does make you wonder why there is no `cat` `builtin`, but there is probably another good explanation for this as well.

Comment: (PS: OP, please excuse my happy sarcasm; I'm all for avoiding unnecessary forks and sane optimizations, but this really doesn't need optimizing.)